# How to round sub-query in Vertica

Tags: sql, database, vertica

How would you round the following output to 3 decimal places in Vertica using ROUND(). I get an error, "Relationship TOTAL does not exist"

```
WITH TOTAL AS
    (
    SELECT 
    SUM(ADV_CPC) AS TOTAL_SPEND,
    COUNT(DISTINCT cc.ID) AS TOTAL_CLICKS,
    COUNT(DISTINCT cv.CLICK_ID) AS TOTAL_CONVERSIONS
    FROM
    clickcache.click cc
    LEFT JOIN clickcache.CONVERSION cv ON
    cv.CLICK_ID = cc.ID
    WHERE
    cc.ADV_ACCOUNT_ID = 14102
    AND AMP_CLICK_DAY = '07-06-2016' 
    AND AMP_CLICK_STATUS_ID = 1
    )
SELECT
ROUND(  COUNT(DISTINCT cc.ID) / (SELECT TOTAL_CLICKS FROM TOTAL), 3.0)  * 100 || '%' AS CLICKS_BY_AGENT
```

Comment: Not enough info, sorry. `TOTAL` is not found in your schema search path and that's all I can really tell you.  Is it in a schema? Try preceding it with the schema name.  schema.table.  Or you can show us the SQL, maybe there is something more fundamentally wrong going on here.

Comment: Please show the entire query.

Comment: I apologize about that guys

Comment: @opamp Ok, I can confirm you're doing something wrong. Sorry!  I attempted to answer your question, but then I realized that the answer is even wrong because the last part of your query just doesn't make any sense. `CLICKS_BY_AGENT` will always be `100%` if I fixed your query as is.  So try explaining to me what the formula is for `CLICKS_BY_AGENT`. What you have right now is basically `TOTAL_CLICKS / TOTAL_CLICKS` when you break it down.  Are you really trying to find the conversion rate? `TOTAL_CONVERSIONS / TOTAL_CLICKS` ?